# Почему при переходе на эту страницу приложение крашится, а при удалении кода все работает,

Tags: java, android-studio

```
package com.example.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class matrix3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button res;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_matrix3);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
        EditText el1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a11);
        EditText el2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a12);
        EditText el3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a13);
        EditText el4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a21);
        EditText el5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a22);
        EditText el6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a23);
        EditText el7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a31);
        EditText el8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a32);
        EditText el9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a33);
        TextView det = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resText);

        int a11 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
        int a12 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
        int a13 = Integer.parseInt(el3.getText().toString());
        int a21 = Integer.parseInt(el4.getText().toString());
        int a22 = Integer.parseInt(el5.getText().toString());
        int a23 = Integer.parseInt(el6.getText().toString());
        int a31 = Integer.parseInt(el7.getText().toString());
        int a32 = Integer.parseInt(el8.getText().toString());
        int a33 = Integer.parseInt(el9.getText().toString());


    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == res) {
        int resSum = (a11 * a22 * a33) + (a21 * a32 * a13) + (a12 * a23 * 
a31) - (a13 * a22 * a31) - (a32 * a23 * a11) - (a21 * a12 * a33);
            det.setText(Integer.toString(resSum));

        }
    }
}
```

Но при удалении данного кода страница работает

Comment: Читайте логи, там написано. Попробуй поставить закрывающую скобку ``}`` метода onCreate перед public void onClick, а не перед блоком со всеми переменным.

Comment: Где в коде кнопка res?

Comment: Всмысле где res?Скобку не получается, все будет подсвечиваться красным

Comment: Вот есть некий объект ``public Button res;`` А где сама кнопка?

Comment: А куда его можно?

Comment: Кого его? На что на экране нажимать?

Comment: На экране имеется кнопка с id = res.Я просто не понял вопроса тогда